# Fatal error when installing ESXi 5.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, formatting

I am trying to install ESXi 5.5 to a computer that ESXi 5.1 is installed before. I am doing installation using the CD-Rom. After I select the boot options in the boot menu, installation starts. After a while, it stops and gives following error.
**Error loading /tools.t00
Fatal error: 10 (Out of resources)**

Can anyone know about this error and help me please? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you doing a wipe or upgrade of the existing server and does the server adhere to the HCL?

Comment: I think server is not adhere to the HCL. I am doing a wipe.

Comment: Well...can you guess what the problem might be, and what we're going to suggest? This isn't a site for experimenters, we're all pro-sysadmins, we like to stick to the HCL.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to System BIOS (Press F2)
2. PCI configuration > MMCFG
3. Change the value from Auto to 2 GB
4. Change the value of Memory Mapped IO above 4 G to Enabled
5. Save and reboot the system
6. Installation will complete

These instructions were formerly posted [here](https://communities.cisco.com/community/technology/datacenter/ucs_management/blog/2014/02/17/error-loading-toolst00-fatal-error-10-out-of-resources-cisco-ucs-c240-m3-server-with-esxi-55) although that page seems to be gone now.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ServerFault. While your answer is technically correct (probably, most likely) it is not a full answer as per our [discussions on link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). If you can please give some explanation or add the relevant text to your answer. So that it may survive the posted link if needed, and contains a fully valid answer within the content of the post.